# How do you play left and right hand Piano according to this player?

Tags: piano

I am trying to mimic, or duplicate the style to this player.  I can't see what he is doing with his left hand?  And, any advise about how to learn his style?  As far as researching his style, yes I have and I believe I need assistance in figuring it out.  The second song can't tell how he is using octaves, doubling the base, and walking base.

Answer (score 1):

This is not complicated. Yes, the left hand is playing the root notes of the chords throughout except in the two bars before the falsetto stuff where the right hand plays the chords F C F C F C. The left hand stays on C throughout those bars.

Apart from those two bars, where it plays on the same syncopated beats as the right hand, the left hand plays on all four beats of every bar - bonk bonk bonk bonk - mostly playing the root notes in octaves. Sometimes he may play the root and the fifth. You won't need more than three fingers on your left hand.

How to learn his style? While counting repeatedly from 1 to 8, practise (US: practice) playing a C in octaves with your left hand on 1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - Keep that going and add a chord of C in the right hand, playing on 1 2 - 4 - 6 - 8. When you can do that you've pretty much mastered what you call his style.

Comment: Thank you old Brixtonian!!  You appear to know your stuff !!  I will move ahead with your advice.

Comment: I was wondering Mr. Brixtonian, if you have time, look at second video, "Caught in a Trap", how he does the base, double base chords? How he is walking the base?

Comment: If you wanted to accept my answer I'd feel more like answering a second. But really it's as guest said, this stuff is not complicated. He seems like a nice guy but his pedalling is horrible! [I wish StackExchange wouldn't question British spellings. "Pedaling?!"]

Comment: I think you all are trying to tell me something....just kidding.  I get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see pretty well what his left hand is doing by looking at the reflection in the piano fallboard.

It's not doing anything so complicated that you need to track every single note.

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering if his left hand is playing the same chord as his right hand, in different inversion or voice?  Same about of notes as right?